# trigger field validation on form submit

Tags: javascript, validation, reactjs

i have a text input component which has a validator input prop for field level validation which gets triggered by event like clicking the field.
I am using the text-input component multiple times in a form. How do i trigger field level validation for all text-inputs on form submit.

```
    <form id="update-for-homeaddress" action="/mycontact" method="POST" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
    <Label labelFor="Nickname" labelText="Nickname:" required/>
        <TextInput inputName="Nickname"
                   inputType="text"
                   value={this.props.myhomeaddress.AddressAlias}
                   onChange={()=>{}}
                   validator={ValidateFactory.getMandatoryCheck()}
                   ref="TextInputRef"
          />
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest moving this code into a  tag below. Put an ID in the form tag

then using this

```
$('document').ready(function()
{

    //Jquery validation codes
    $("#my_form").validate({
     submitHandler: submitForm
       });

    function submitForm()
    {
        //Submit form from here
    }
}
```

You need the jquery validation plugin here, you can add different validations then on

https://jqueryvalidation.org

I hope this helps in any way.